# Issue with overloading >> operator in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, cin

I have a class `CMusic` with 3 member variables. I want to enter them by first declaring an object, and then `cin` from the console. However, the compiler does not like my operator overloading function for the `>>` operator. I would like to ask why this happens? Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

      class CMusic {
            string m_strArtist;
            string m_strTitle;
            int m_iYear;
        public:
            CMusic() {
                m_strArtist = "Vivaldi";
                m_strTitle = "The 4 Seasons";
                m_iYear = 1723;
            }
            friend istream& operator>> (istream& is, CMusic ms) {
                is >> ms.getArtist();
                is >> ms.getTitle();
                is >> ms.getYear();
                return is;
            }
        };
    int main(){
    CMusic msc;
    cin>>msc;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to an `operator>>` overload needs to be a non-const reference to the object you want to read into.  By passing a copy of the object, you would read into that temp copy and throw it away, not actually updating the object you're trying to read into.  So it needs to be something like:

```
        friend istream& operator>> (istream& is, CMusic &ms) {
            is >> ms.m_strArtist;
            is >> ms.m_strTitle;
            is >> ms.m_iYear;
            return is;
        }
```